# maven install not work in eclipse and trying other plans

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]
Error logs:

```
[INFO] 

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] 

[INFO] 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-
plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project sample: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

================================================================

I try plans.

1. preferences > maven > user settings reset
2. project clean > maven update > maven clean > maven install
3. C:\Users\docan.m2\repository  folder delete and try step2

Comment: Can you post you pom.xml . this is suspicious Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: Based on the error you have you are using either JDK 6 or 7 but not correctly updated the configuration to use TLSv1.2. You should change your Maven call to: `mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 clean package`....